# Number formatting in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I want to format decimal number in Kendo UI in invariant culture(only decimal delimiter which is period) with two digits after decimal delimiter.
I want 12345.2343 to be shown as 12345.23 not culture dependent format like 12,345.23 or 12345,23 or something like that.

I user function:

```
kendo.toString(myNumber, 'n2')
```

Regards

Comment: Where do you want to show this value? In a Kendo Grid cell or some other widget?

Comment: In kendo grid column template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying this way:

```
kendo.toString(myNumber, '0.00')
```

If you want a culture, specify that first, but that will insert commas which I understand you do not want.

```
kendo.culture("en-US");
```

See here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/intl/numberformatting